# Fluent Validating on Quantity in the Shopping Cart nopcommerce

Tags: validation, model-view-controller, nopcommerce

I need to validate the quantity box on the shopping cart. I know it can't be "NotEmpty" and must be a number. I've modified the whole site to except "Decimals" but I need to validate that field to except only numbers in the range of .25, .5, .75. I have the following algorithm which does the job in one of my own projects but I just can't work out where to put it in nopcommerce, using Fluent Validation.

```
public class ValNumber
{
    [RegularExpression(@"^\d+(\.(25|5|75|0)0*)?$", ErrorMessage = "The value must be **.25, **.5 or **.75")]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Properties.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "CannotBeBlank")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency, ErrorMessage = "Must be a number!")]
    public decimal valnumber { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I was hoping that was the case but how do I write the if statement, the actual syntax.

Right now I have:

```
if (quantity != "Need the RegEx syntax in here!")
{
    warnings.Add(string.Format("Must be in the range of .25, .5 or .75"));
}
```

Comment: Have u tried putting it on model property for quantity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing your update:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(quantity, @"Your regex goes here"))
{
  //do your success thing
}
else
{
  warnings.Add(string.Format("Must be in the range of .25, .5 or .75"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael but the problem is the error "The name 'Regex' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: just needed using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Answer (score 2):

ShoppingCartItem doesn't really use FluentValidation like some of the other objects.  I would put your validation in Nop.Services.Orders.ShoppingCartService GetStandardWarnings() which also does some other quantity validation.

Comment: Thanks Andy, I'm using version 2.5 and I don't seem to have a GetStandardWarnings function in the whole solution. I have an AddToCart and UpdateShoppingCartItem functions with lots of Add.warnings in it, and a bunch of redundant code. Am I close to the mark here! It's **newQuantity** in UpdateShoppingCartItem I should be dealing with, isn't it?

Comment: For 2.5 your best bet is Nop.Services.Orders.ShoppingCartService GetShoppingCartItemWarnings()

Comment: Thanks Andy, do you have an example of what I should write in there. I've only ever used RegularExpression in model classes?

Comment: You could use the same RegEx you were planning on, just add your error message to the warnings list if it doesn't match.  If there are any warnings in the list it will fail to add the item to the cart and will display them to the customer.

Comment: I have made a comment above